# Chart.js Start Y-Axis at a defined value

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

A Plugin that I use on my website use Chart.js
I try to start Y-Axis at a defined value.

Here's a picture of what I have now :
Line Chart
[image]

the javascript code :

```
(function() {
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name:'UncontinuousLine',
    defaults:{scaleBeginAtZero:false},
    initialize:function(data) {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this,arguments);
    },
    draw:function() {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this,arguments);
        var ctx=this.chart.ctx;
        this.datasets.forEach(function(ds) {
            ctx.strokeStyle=ds.strokeColor;
            var prevPt={value:2.49};
            ds.points.forEach(function(curPt) {
                if(parseInt(curPt.value)<=0) {
                    curPt.value=prevPt.value;
                } 
                if(parseInt(curPt.value)>0&&parseInt(prevPt.value)>0) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.moveTo(prevPt.x,prevPt.y);
                    ctx.lineTo(curPt.x,curPt.y);
                    ctx.stroke();
                } 
                prevPt=curPt;
            });
        });

    }
});})();
```

and the php code :

```
private function _create_uncontinuousline_chart( $data, $opt ){ 
    if ( empty( $data ) ){ 
        return '';
    } 
    $id = self::_get_canvas_id( $this->count );
    $sets = self::_parse_data( $data, 3 );
    $cd = self::_resort_sets( $sets, true );
    $this->js[] = 'new Chart(' . "jQuery('#$id').get(0).getContext('2d')" . ')
                    .UncontinuousLine(' . AimyChartsContentPluginHelper::phpva_json_encode( $cd ) . ',' 
                    . '{' . 'animation: ' . ( $opt[ 'animate' ] ? 'true' : 'false' ) . ',' 
                    . 'multiTooltipTemplate: ' . '"<%= value %> (<%= datasetLabel %>)"' 
                    . ',responsive: ' . ( $opt[ 'responsive' ] ? 'true' : 'false' ) 
                    . ',datasetStrokeWidth:0.01' . '}' . ');';
    return self::_get_canvas( 'UncontinuousLine', $this->count, $opt );
}
```

I've tried many things but impossible to start my y-axis at 1 for example...
Does someone know how i can do that ?

Comment: look at the option scaleOverride, scaleSteps, scaleStepWidth and scaleStartValue

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for your reply.
I've tried but either I did not do it at the right place, or it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In your options, use this:

```
 scaleBeginAtZero : false,
 scaleOverride: true,
 scaleStartValue: 1,
```

Try this for your php code:

```
private function _create_uncontinuousline_chart( $data, $opt ){ 
    if ( empty( $data ) ){ 
        return '';
    } 
    $id = self::_get_canvas_id( $this->count );
    $sets = self::_parse_data( $data, 3 );
    $cd = self::_resort_sets( $sets, true );
    $this->js[] = 'new Chart(' . "jQuery('#$id').get(0).getContext('2d')" . ')
                    .UncontinuousLine(' . AimyChartsContentPluginHelper::phpva_json_encode( $cd ) . ',' 
                    . '{' . 'animation: ' . ( $opt[ 'animate' ] ? 'true' : 'false' )  
                    . ',multiTooltipTemplate: ' . '"<%= value %> (<%= datasetLabel %>)"' 
                    . ',responsive: ' . ( $opt[ 'responsive' ] ? 'true' : 'false' ) 
                    . ',datasetStrokeWidth:0.01' 
                    . ',scaleBeginAtZero : false'
                    . ',scaleOverride: true'
                    . ',scaleStartValue: 1'
                    . '}' . ');';
    return self::_get_canvas( 'UncontinuousLine', $this->count, $opt );
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help. I'm using extend because I've sometimes null values, So I wanted to cut my graph in that case but after reflexion, recover the previous values is more interesting.
I've tried to add this in my option but that doesn't work (I put it in my php after ',datasetStrokeWidth:0.01' is that there ?)

Comment: Updated my answer to include a php code snippet that I THINK will work with your current setup, Do you have a place that this can be viewed publicly? perhaps put it on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Hello, I've tried that before but if I do that the chart disapear (cf : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/12/1458546932-chart.jpg ). On the other side, the values appears in the window that appears on hover. I don't now how to put it on jsfiddle.net because that works with a joomla plugin. Thank's anyway.

Comment: If the values appear in the tooltip, then we have the data right, it's just got something with it's config,if I can see the output( the graph) then I can see what's wrong on that side and figure a fix. Got a url for me?

Comment: Hey, my site is in local for the moment. Data are right yes but as we can see on the last screenshot the y-axis start at 0. The only difference being that lines don't appear any more. I believe that that is going to stay like that for the moment. With a little luck, one day that will be proposed by the creators of the plugin. Thank you for the time you've taken!

Comment: I would really like to help you here, because I've had experience with Chart.js and heavily modifying it, I have no doubt that I could help you with this issue. if you'd like, e-mail me at gregborbonus@gmail.com